# How to cancel copy table from PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've executed the copy table operation from PhpMyAdmin and it is taking too long (big table), and now the original and new table are not responding (I can browse the other tables in PhpMyAdmin)

I think because maybe there is a read lock or something worst, is possible to cancel the operation or see at least what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible things - first, you could restart the webserver to stop any running PHP scripts. That might help if PHPMyAdmin copies the data in batches.

Second, you can execute `show full processlist` query to see all running queries. Identifying the hung query should not be too hard. Then use `kill <pid>` query (replace the  with the actual process ID) to kill that query.

Comment: Is also possible to restart mysql or I could break my database? I don't care the new copy tale, but I don't want to loose the original one

Comment: using PHP I can read the original table, but not the new one (the copy). From PhpMyAdmin I cannot read any of them, I've tried with a select query from PhpMyAdmin (same one executing with PHP) and it says: "#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Comment: @Enrique As long as you do a graceful restart, it should be OK, I think. But killing the offending query should be enough. Yes, the new table might be inaccessible, but, as you said, you don't really need it. Drop it. The copy operation should only read the old table, so there's no reason why it should be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

On phpMyAdmin's main page, go to Status > Processes. You should be seeing one process with a large value under Time; use the Kill link to stop it.

Comment: I see just one process and with time 0. The strange thing is I can browse all the tables, except the one I was copying. Any clue?

Comment: @Enrique - Perhaps it's some sort of issue with PHPMyAdmin, rather than MySQL? Have you tried logging off and restarting your browser?

Comment: I think PhpMyAdmin is having some problem yes, because with PHP I can read the original table, but if I try to read the new table the MySQL is disconnected (maybe the new table was not created correctly and giving errors? but I'm not sure if MySQL stills working on the copy table, and if it is safe to drop it in that case (safe for the database, I don't care the new table)

Comment: @Enrique Which phpMyAdmin version is this? Also, when you open your database, do you see any warning next to these two table names?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin: 4.8.3, no warning, but when I try to access that particular table it shows the "loading" forever, then MySQL is disconnected (receive error 500). If I enter to PhpMyAdmin again it works again (it seems MySQL is restarted automatically, maybe some daemon) but that particular table never works!

Comment: Did you try repairing the table? It might work depending on its storage engine. Open the database, then tick this table and at the bottom "with selected... repair table".